# javascript color change not working

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First JavaScript</h1>

<p id="demo">
JavaScript can change the style of an HTML element.
</p>

<script>
function myFunction()
{ 
  x=document.getElementById("demo") 
  if (x.style.color="#000000")
  {
    x.style.color="#FF0000"; 
    //alert(x.style.color);
  }
  else
  {
    x.style.color="#000000"; 
    //alert(x.style.color);
  }
}
</script>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Click Me!</button>

</body>
</html>
```

above code not working second time Click

i tried with many different colors

x.style.color not accepting in else block

else block not working

please help

Comment: You should consider using JQuery, so you can toggle your colors and use a lot of other useful things. Your function would become a one-liner.

Comment: One line plus almost 100 kilobytes of minified jQuery…

Comment: i am trying to learn javascript @Robert

Comment: You must also use `==` for comparison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different browsers might return different values for the same colors. You better use different logic to toggle the colors. What I suggest, using pure JavaScript, is this:

```
var demoColors = ["#000000", "#FF0000"];
var demoFlag = true;
function myFunction()
{ 
    var demo = document.getElementById("demo");
    demo.style.color = demoColors[+demoFlag]
    demoFlag = !demoFlag;
}
```

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/tK8te/).

Answer (score 4):

A) use `==` instead of `=` in the `if` condition statement 
B) check against *rgb* color notation and not hex

```
function myFunction() {

    x = document.getElementById("demo");
    if (x.style.color == "rgb(0, 0, 0)") {
        x.style.color = "#FF0000";
    } else {

        x.style.color = "#000000";
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4QUWq/1/

Answer (score 2):

When I test in chrome, color is rgb(255, 0, 0) that's why the if condition is always false. And your assigning in the if and not comparing (= vs ==)
Take a look at: [Javascript - Converting colors (numbers -> strings) vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9695687/javascript-converting-colors-numbers-strings-vice-versa)

Answer (score 0):

When performing a comparison such as in a conditional use `==` instead of `=`.  `=` is the assignment operator.  After changing the comparison operator you must use `rgb` instead of the color code.

```
function myFunction()
{ 
  x=document.getElementById("demo");
  if (x.style.color=="rgb(0, 0, 0)")
  {
    x.style.color="#FF0000"; 
    //alert(x.style.color);
  }
  else
  {
    x.style.color="#000000"; 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `style.backgroundColor`.

It returns name of the color or in RGB format so you will have to convert it.

Answer (score 0):

Use rgb color notation instead of hex

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First JavaScript</h1>

 <p id="demo">
 JavaScript can change the style of an HTML element.
 </p>

 <script>
 function myFunction() {

 x = document.getElementById("demo");
 if (x.style.color == "rgb(0, 0, 0)") {
    x.style.color = "#FF0000";
   } 
  else {

    x.style.color = "#000000";
 }
}
</script>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Click Me!</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const counter = document.querySelector('#counter')
const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.btn')

let count = 0

btns.forEach((btn) => {
    btn.addEventListener('click' ,(e) => {
         const styles = e.currentTarget.classList

    if (styles.contains('increase')) {
        count++
    }else if (styles.contains('decrease')) {
        count--
    } else {
        count=0
    }
    //section 01
    if (count>0 ) {
        counter.style.color == "red"
    }
    //section 02
    if (count < 0 ) {
        counter.style.color = "#ff0000"
    } 
    //section 03
    if (count === 0) {
        counter.style.color == "red"
    }

    counter.textContent = count
 })
})
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).