# Changing the color of the ball to a random colour every time it hits the wall

Tags: javascript, function, canvas, html5-canvas

I want to change color of the dot every time it hits the wall. I saw few solutions, but I don't know why mine isn't working.

Here's the part responsible for changing color:

```
function chColor() {
    hex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000 + 1);
    color = '"' + "#" + hex + '"';
    color.toString();
    return color;
}
```

And here is not working fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/vpzd7ye6/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in converting number to hex color string.
So you can write a function that converts random number to valid hex color (see [what this function does](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9695716/5091346)):

```
function convertToColor(num){
    return '#' + ('00000' + (num | 0).toString(16)).substr(-6);
}
```

and then just use it in `chColor` function:

```
function chColor() {
    number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000 + 1);
    color = convertToColor(number);
    return color;
}
```

Here is the link with working example: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/frwhcgms/)

---

Also it makes sense to rename function to `getRandomColor`:

```
function getRandomColor(){
    number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000 + 1);
    return convertToColor(number);
}
```

Comment: @user3516973 if it solved your problem, please mark this post as an answer

Comment: @user3516973 I think it's fair to mark Andrii Ambrov answer as correct because he was first and his answer is correct. However please also consider my one. It can be a bit more clean :)
Btw THUMB UP AndriiAbramov

Comment: @Andurit thank you. your answer also makes sense. One for you too.

Answer (score 1):

Please check updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vpzd7ye6/3/)

I just changed your `chColor` function on this:

```
  function chColor() {
    color = "#" + ((1 << 24) * Math.random() | 0).toString(16);
    return color;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

### Colour overkill

This answer is **way** overkill and I was about to discard it, but, why not give a Better random colour for those who may need it...  <sup>**(|:***D*</sup>

**When random seams less random**

Selecting a random totally random colour for us humans does not work that well if you wish to have a clear distinct change that attracts the eye from one colour to the next.

The problem is that many of the colour values available are very close to white or black and a totally random colour may be very close to the last making the change impossible to notice.

**Simple random colour**

So first the simple random colour picks a totally random colour from all of the 16,777,216 possible colours.

```
function randColor(){
    return "#" + 
           (Math.floor(Math.random() * 0x1000000) + 0x1000000)
              .toString(16)
              .substr(1);
}
```

The function works by finding a random 24 bit number (`0` - `0xFFFFFF` same as 0 - 16777216). Because numbers do not have leading zeros added all random values below `0x100000` will, when converted to hex have less than 6 digit (the CSS colour value requires 3 or 6 digit Hex value) so I add `0x1000000` to ensure that the number is > `0x100000` and will always have 7 digits. As the first (left most) digit is not needed I use `substr` to remove it. Then added the `"#"` and return.

The function `Number.toString(radix)` takes an argument called `radix` which specifies the base the number is converted to. It defaults if not supplied to 10 (base ten is what we humans use). The hex colour is base 16 so that must be specified. The `toString` radix argument can be any value from 2 (binary) to 36 (which uses characters 0-9 then A-Z)

**Less is more Random**

Ironically we humans tend to find less random sequences more random than true random sequences. Many music players use this type of random sequence when they have the play set to shuffle, to ensure tracks are not played twice in a row or that repeated sequences of tracks are played by random chance.

To make the random colour seem more random and distinct you should track the last colour return so that you can ensure you are not close to that colour. You should also use a random colour that stays away from the whites and blacks.

```
var randColour = (function(){ // as singleton so closure can track last colour
    var lastHue = 0;
    const minChange = 360 / 3; // Hue distance from last random colour
    var lastVal = false; // for low high saturation and luminance
    const randomAmount = 360 / 3; // random hue range
    const minVal = 20; // how far from full black white to stay (percent)
    const minSat = 80; // how far from grey to stay (percent)
    return function(){
         var hueChange = Math.random() * randomAmount ;
         hueChange *= Math.random() < 0.5 ? -1 : 1; // randomly move forward or backward
         lastHue += 360 + hueChange + minChange;  // move away from last colour
         lastHue %= 360;  // ensure colour is in valid range
         var sat = (Math.random() * (100 - minSat)) + minSat; // get saturation (amount of colour)
         var val = (Math.random() * (50 - minVal * 2)) * 1.5; // get value (luminance)
         // switch between high and low and luminance
         lastVal = ! lastVal;
         if(lastVal){        
             val = minVal + val;
         } else {
             val = 100 - minVal - val;
         }


         return "hsl(" + lastHue.toFixed(0) + "," + sat.toFixed(0) + "%," + val.toFixed(0) + "%)";
     }
})(); // call singleton
```

This function returns a random colour but ensures that the saturation and value stay within a specific range and that the hue is at least 1/3 around the colour wheel from the last value. It cycles between low and low and high luminance values to make the colour change as clear as possible. Closure is used to keep track of the last colour returned. The function returns the random colour as a CSS `hsl(hue, saturation, luminance)` color string.

There are two constants that control the colour sequence. `minVal` set to 20 is the percentage to stay away from full black or full white. Valid range is 0-~50 and `minSat` set to 80 is how far to stay away from grays in percent.
        const minSat = 80; // how far from grey to stay (percent)

**Compare change**

To compare the two methods the following demo shows side by side a set of random colours using both methods, then flashes a new random colour 4 times a second. The simple random colour will appear from time to time to miss a change. I leave it up to you to pick which side is which.

```js
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = 620;
canvas.height = 200;
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

var randColour = (function(){ // as singleton so closure can track last colour
    var lastHue = 0;
    const minChange = 360 / 3; // min hue change
    var lastVal = false; // for low high saturation and luminance
    const randomAmount = 360 / 3; // amount of randomness
    const minVal = 20; // how far from full black white to stay (percent)
    const minSat = 80; // how far from grey to stay (percent)
    return function(){
         var hueChange = Math.random() * randomAmount ;
         hueChange *= Math.random() < 0.5 ? -1 : 1; // randomly move forward or backward
         lastHue += 360 + hueChange + minChange;  // move away from last colour
         lastHue %= 360;  // ensure colour is in valid range
         var sat = (Math.random() * (100 - minSat)) + minSat; // get saturation (amount of colour)
         var val = (Math.random() * (50 - minVal * 2)) * 1.5; // get value (luminance)
         // switch between high and low and luminance
         lastVal = ! lastVal;
         if(lastVal){        
             val = minVal + val;
         } else {
             val = 100 - minVal - val;
         }
            

         return "hsl(" + lastHue.toFixed(0) + "," + sat.toFixed(0) + "%," + val.toFixed(0) + "%)";
     }
})(); // call singleton

function randColor(){
    return "#" + 
           (Math.floor(Math.random() * 0x1000000) + 0x1000000)
              .toString(16)
              .substr(1);
}

const grid = 16; 
var gridX = 0;
var gridY = 0;
var bigSize = grid - (grid / 3 ) * 2;
const xStep = Math.floor((canvas.width - 12) / (grid * 2));
const yStep = Math.floor(canvas.height / grid);
var count = 0;
function drawRandomColour(){
     ctx.fillStyle = randColor(); // simple random colour
     ctx.fillRect(gridX * xStep, gridY * yStep, xStep, yStep);
     ctx.fillStyle = randColour(); // smart random colour
     ctx.fillRect(gridX * xStep + canvas.width / 2, gridY * yStep, xStep, yStep);

     if(count < grid * grid - 1){  // fill the grid
         gridX += 1;  // move to next grid
         if(gridX > grid-1){
             gridX = 0;
             gridY += 1;
             gridY %= grid;
         }
         count += 1;
         setTimeout(drawRandomColour,1); // quickly fill grid
         return; // done for now
     }
     // if grid is full pick a random grid loc and request the next random colour
     gridY = gridX = (grid / 3);
     setTimeout(centerChange,250); // every quarter second
     
 }
 function centerChange(){
     ctx.fillStyle = randColor(); // simple random colour
     ctx.fillRect(gridX * xStep, gridY * yStep, xStep * bigSize, yStep * bigSize);
     ctx.fillStyle = randColour(); // smart random colour
     ctx.fillRect(gridX * xStep + canvas.width / 2, gridY * yStep, xStep * bigSize, yStep * bigSize);
     setTimeout(centerChange,250); // every quarter second
 }

 drawRandomColour(); // start it up.
```

**Compare sequences**

This demo just draws the random colours as a sequence of random values. Examine the sequences to see how often you see two or more colours in a row that are hard to distinguish between. You will find that the sequence on the left has more similar sequences than the one on the right.

Expand demo to full-page view to see both sequences.

Click to redraw sequences.

```js
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = 1240;
canvas.height = 800;
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

var randColour = (function(){ // as singleton so closure can track last colour
    var lastHue = 0;
    const minChange = 360 / 3; // min hue change
    var lastVal = false; // for low high saturation and luminance
    const randomAmount = 360 / 3; // amount of randomness
    const minVal = 20; // how far from full black white to stay (percent)
    const minSat = 80; // how far from grey to stay (percent)
    return function(){
         var hueChange = Math.random() * randomAmount ;
         hueChange *= Math.random() < 0.5 ? -1 : 1; // randomly move forward or backward
         lastHue += 360 + hueChange + minChange;  // move away from last colour
         lastHue %= 360;  // ensure colour is in valid range
         var sat = (Math.random() * (100 - minSat)) + minSat; // get saturation (amount of colour)
         var val = (Math.random() * (50 - minVal * 2)) * 1.5; // get value (luminance)
         // switch between high and low and luminance
         lastVal = ! lastVal;
         if(lastVal){        
             val = minVal + val;
         } else {
             val = 100 - minVal - val;
         }
            

         return "hsl(" + lastHue.toFixed(0) + "," + sat.toFixed(0) + "%," + val.toFixed(0) + "%)";
     }
})(); // call singleton

function randColor(){
    return "#" + 
           (Math.floor(Math.random() * 0x1000000) + 0x1000000)
              .toString(16)
              .substr(1);
}

const grid = 32; 
var gridX = 0;
var gridY = 0;
const xStep = Math.floor((canvas.width - 12) / (grid * 2));
const yStep = Math.floor(canvas.height / grid);
var count = 0;
function drawRandomColour(){
     ctx.fillStyle = randColor(); // simple random colour
     ctx.fillRect(gridX * xStep, gridY * yStep, xStep, yStep);
     ctx.fillStyle = randColour(); // smart random colour
     ctx.fillRect(gridX * xStep + canvas.width / 2, gridY * yStep, xStep, yStep);

     if(count < grid * grid - 1){  // fill the grid
         gridX += 1;  // move to next grid
         if(gridX > grid-1){
             gridX = 0;
             gridY += 1;
             gridY %= grid;
         }
         count += 1;
         setTimeout(drawRandomColour,1); // quickly fill grid
         return; // done for now
     }
 }

 drawRandomColour(); // start it up.

 // redraw on click
 canvas.addEventListener("click",function(){
     if(count >= grid * grid - 1){
          gridX = gridY = count = 0;
          drawRandomColour();
     }else { 
          gridX = gridY = count = 0;

     }
 });
```

**Summary**

Though the second random function is not perfect, It can from time to time get colours that within a context appear similar this occurs much less than by pure random. When it is important for the user to notice a visual changes the best approch is to cycle two complementary colours (hue + 180) with one having a high luminance and the other a low. The CSS hsl colour string makes it easy to pick luminance and hue and when you want random colours gives you better control.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the fiddle. Link https://jsfiddle.net/vpzd7ye6/2/

I made the following change to your change color function;

```
function chColor() {
        hex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000) + 1;
        color = '' + '#' + hex + '';
        return color;
}
```